# Excel macro to insert blank cells that are different from each other

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert a blank cells that are different from each other; in this case colA and colB.

What I'm trying to insert a blank cell if ColB if different from ColA

Input is

```
ColA ColB
1      1
2      2
3      4
4
```

output should be

```
ColA ColB
1      1
2      2
3     Blank cel
4      4
```

Comment: Are missing values only in ColB?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below ?

```
For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Not Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value Then
        Cells(i, 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Cells(i, 2).Value = "Blank Cell"
    End If
Next i
```